# What are the reasons for a group not showing in a win32 listview?

Tags: listview, winapi, controls

In newer versions of the common control library, the listview supports groups. When I use the listview macros to add a group, the group doesn't show up in the listview. What are the reason that the listview control might not show the groups that have been added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Enable the group view on the listview before adding the group to the listview. You can use the [ListView_EnableGroupView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro or the LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW message to achieve this.
2. The listview must have the top alignment window style. You can set this style in the resource editor for the listview control or apply it using [LVS_ALIGNTOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
3. The group must have items associated with it. If the group does not have any items associated it may not show. When inserting an item into the listview you must specify the group id using LVITEM's iGroupId property. Note that the iGroup property of [LVITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is read-only and should not be used for specifying which group an item belongs to.
4. The group must have items associated with it in order for it to show. If you are setting an item's group after both the item and the group have been created make sure that you are not using the [ListView_MoveItemToGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro which is only available on Windows CE. Instead you can set the item's group using the ListView_SetItem macro.

   ```
   LVITEMA Item = {0};


   Item.mask = LVIF_GROUPID;
   Item.iItem = Index;
   Item.iGroupId = GroupId;

   if (ListView_SetItem(hWnd, &Item) == FALSE)
       return FALSE;
   return TRUE;
   ```
5. The listview cannot be in "List" mode as it is unsupported.
6. The listview cannot be an ownerdrawn listview it is also unsupported.
7. The [application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#using_manifests) must specify version 6.0 or higher of the common controls library.
8. Ensure that when you call InitCommonControlsEx you do not include the ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES flag as in some cases it might prevent the listview control from displaying groups.

Additional resources:

- [Arranging List Items by Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Group_View)
- [The ListView grouping feature (in Windows XP)](http://users.skynet.be/oleole/Listview_grouping_feature.htm)
- [Enabling Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#using_manifests)

Comment: I want to add one simple (in retrospect) check. But it just killed me an hour of feverish debugging. My listbox just stopped showing anything when groups enabled, despite in my tests "can I add groups here" a bit ago - it worked. In retrospect it is stupid, but finding it was hard. So, I use some object-oriented library over Windows API. Typically all properties unless explicitly changed are zeroed out. So when I introduced groups to show one special case that was hidden before, I added groups #0 and #1. I tested quickly - and there were groups. Then I reworked database reading code to have

Comment: meaningful data - and voila - the listbox was always empty in GroupView mode and only showed a thing in non-GroupView mode. I started with database code (I just tested GUI code it worked) then this, then that, your checklist, other checklists. It was stupid, but apart from the conventions, in this specific place newly created Item had GroupID as -1 instead of zero. And by chance data I used to load was never triggering GroupID := 1 set of conditions. So ALL my rows fallen to non-existent group "-1" and were hidden. Obvious in retrospect, but very unnerving when u just see no data for no reason